# MySQL query 'going away' on executing INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE statement with a 12524 character blob

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, storage-engine

I have a mysql insert on update query like so

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (1,2,'huge blob with 12524 chars') on duplicate key update col3 = 'huge blob with 12524 chars';
```

- col1, col2 is a composite key and it has index on it.
- There are a total of 91 records in table
- All other blobs in table have less than 1000 chars
- If I give col3 a small value then this query runs instantly
- If I give a small value in the insert part but large value in the update part it takes 5 seconds to execute
- If I give large value in insert part but small value in second part it dies with a 1 minute timeout.

What could be causing this query to die on execution after being stuck for 1 minute?
What should I look at?

What could be causing this query to take so long to execute and dying if blob value is huge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you have to increase the size of your MySQL Packets

According to the [page 99 of "Understanding MySQL Internals" (ISBN 0-596-00957-7)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577), here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Since MySQL Packets can hold rows of data, larger items in the packet can cause a lot of packets to filter in-and-out to prevent whole chunks of related data from splitting during processing. This can be a silent killer of DB connections for no apparent reason. [If fact, I wrote a post about how this can affect certain mysqldumps.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323)

Try increasing the max_allowed_packet (256M) using the following command:

```
SET max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
```