# How to optimize MySQL for large BLOB updates

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-tuning

I have a table that holds large BLOBs (up to 10M), and is updated frequently. The problem is that UPDATE statements can take up to 1 second to execute, and due to app design this blocks UI. I need to speed up those  UPDATE/INSERT statements. Is there a way to do it by tuning MySQL server/storage engine/etc?

The table in question is InnoDB, and I have tried tunring compression on, but that didn't seem to make a lot of difference. Client is on the same machine as server so there is no network overhead. Server is MySQL 5.5

Comment: Are you using Amazon MySQL RDS ???

Comment: No, this is our own XenServer + Nexenta

Answer (score 4):

**This looks like a job for InnoDB Architecture Tuning !!!**

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Where can BLOB data become a bottleneck for InnoDB? Three places

## Place #1 : InnoDB Log File

The size of the InnoDB Log Files (set by [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)) could be a bottleneck if there are many transactions being written that update BLOB data.

## Place #2 : InnoDB Log Buffer

The InnoDB Log Buffer (set by [**innodb_log_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size)) can be a bad bottleneck if it it set smaller that the BLOB itself. The default is 8M. You may need to resize it to accommodate multiple rows that have that BLOBs. Perhaps 128M would be a good place to start. That can also reduce disk I/O when writing to the InnoDB Log Files.

## Place #3 : The MySQL Packet

What is a MySQL Packet?

According to [the Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577)

[image: Understanding MySQL Internals]

Page 99 Paragraphs 1-3 explains it as follows:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Anytime there is transmission of MySQL Data, the MySQL Packet channels MySQL Data into the OS and network. Like the InnoDB Log Buffer, the MySQL Packet must accommodate multiple BLOBs as well.

## EPILOGUE

I have discussed this topics in the past

- `Nov 22, 2011` : [MySQL query 'going away' on executing INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE statement with a 12524 character blob](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/mysql-query-going-away-on-executing-insert-on-duplicate-update-statement-with/8260#8260)
- `Aug 01, 2011` : [How does max_allowed_packet affect the  backup and restore of a database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/how-does-max-allowed-packet-affect-the-backup-and-restore-of-a-database/4231#4231)
- `Apr 27, 2011` : [Changed max_allowed_packet and still receiving 'Packet Too Large' error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/886/changed-max-allowed-packet-and-still-receiving-packet-too-large-error/2383#2383)

## CAVEAT

Compression may have made things a little worse. Why ?

When compress an InnoDB table, any time data and index pages for that table is read, the page and an uncompressed copy of the page coexist in the InnoDB Buffer Pool. If you want to keep the table compressed, you must expand the [InnoDB Buffer Pool (set by innodb_buffer_pool_size)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size). I wrote about this as well as an update to an old answer of mine : [innodb_file_format Barracuda](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/innodb-file-format-barracuda/14287#14287)

## UPDATE 2013-07-19 16:11 EST

Based on your last comment

> Initial impressions: while tuning InnoDB buffers helped a bit, it seems like more improvement came from turning off binary logs for this particular table. Still monitoring the performance...

I have a suggestion

You may need to rearchitect your InnoDB files so that all `.ibd` files are on the data volume, while other MySQL components (ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, all binary logs) could be mounted on another disk. I wrote about this before in a post about PostgreSQL : [Postgres Write Performance on Intel S3700 SSD](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45224/postgres-write-performance-on-intel-s3700-ssd/45228#45228), The person asking that question said he got a 10% increase in performance.

## UPDATE 2013-07-26 15:33 EST

Since I asked

> QUESTIONS : 1) How much RAM is on the DB Server? 2) What is the result of SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';; 3) What do you get when you run`SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';`?

and you said

> 8gb RAM, 4gb available to MySQL. 'innodb_file_per_table', 'ON'. SUM is 3316736000

I recommend the following (if you have not already done so)

- Set [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) to 3G
- Set [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) to 1G

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer! My innodb_log_file_size was already increased to 96M, changed that to 128M, increased pool size to 128M as well. max_packet was already at 1G. Tests seem to indicate that updates are indeed much faster, I am seeing ~100ms. I'll put in the changes on production system, and if the results are the same will accept the answer.

Comment: Initial impressions: while tuning InnoDB buffers helped a bit, it seems like more improvement came from turning off binary logs for this particular table. Still monitoring the performance...

Comment: Unfortunately it is still lagging. We use New Relic agent, and it is showing us UPDATE operations that last up to 7 seconds. Oddly enough INSERTs are not a problem...

Comment: QUESTIONS : 1) How much RAM is on the DB Server? 2) What is the result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';`; 3) What do you get when you run`SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';`?

Comment: 8gb RAM, 4gb available to MySQL. 'innodb_file_per_table', 'ON'. SUM is 3316736000

Comment: Thanks, will try the suggestion! I have to take our production server down for this so it'll have to wait until next week...

Answer (score 1):

1) For a table with several columns, to reduce memory requirements for queries that do not use the BLOB column, consider splitting the BLOB column into a separate table and referencing it with a join query when needed.

2) since the performance requirements to retrieve and display a BLOB value might be very different from other data types, you could put the BLOB-specific table on a different storage device or even a separate database instance. For example, to retrieve a BLOB might require a large sequential disk read that is better suited to a traditional hard drive than to an SSD device.

You can refer this existing SO link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318961/optimizing-mysql-files-in-database-blob

Comment: The table in question already contains only the blob column. Besides, its UPDATE/INSERT statement that I'm looking to optimize, not SELECT. Putting blobbed table on separate device wont help as this is virtualized environment. How about a RAM disk?